# Centering a photo

Tags: html, css, center, photo

[image]

Hey, I'm not sure how to center this photo. It is slightly offset as you can see and I would like to make a few divs side by side with breaks and add the photos but unfortunately they are not perfectly centered.

I would appreciate some advice for the future on how to center images well in the css file.

```css
.Photos {
  color: black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.photo1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 450px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://optimagas.com/blog/bl-content/uploads/pages/e931fad50039f497fa1b5438c6cd89c9/gazziemny.jpg);
}
```

```html
<section class="Photos">
  <div class="photo1">fsgfsd</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you want it to be reduced in size to fit, or do you want to be cropped, but with equal cropping on both edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **background-position: center;**

```css
.Photos {
  color: black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.photo1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 450px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://optimagas.com/blog/bl-content/uploads/pages/e931fad50039f497fa1b5438c6cd89c9/gazziemny.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="Photos">
  <div class="photo1">fsgfsd</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use flex to align content inside the element to center

```
.Photos {
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 450px;
}
```

You can also do the same thing using margin

```
.Photos {
  color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```css
.Photos {
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-item: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.photo1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://optimagas.com/blog/bl-content/uploads/pages/e931fad50039f497fa1b5438c6cd89c9/gazziemny.jpg);
  width: 25%;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<section class="Photos">
  <div class="photo1">fsgfsd</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use Flex or grid,**

```
.Photos {
  color: black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  text-align: center; /* Center the content horizontally */
}

.photo1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 450px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://optimagas.com/blog/bl-content/uploads/pages/e931fad50039f497fa1b5438c6cd89c9/gazziemny.jpg);
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the div horizontally */
}
```